# Interacting with MATLAB while a dialog is open

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

The default behavior of MATLAB question dialog is that it prevents the user from interacting with other windows before responding.

I need that the user can still click on some links that I've printed on the command window earlier but `questdlg` does not let it happen.

Is there a way to let the user interact with other windows? or a workaround? thanks

Comment: You'll need to make your own dialog GUI. As the documentation for [`questdlg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html) states, `questdlg` opens a `'modal'` window, which [displays on top of all existing figure windows, making them inaccessible as long as the top figure exists and remains modal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_windowstyle).

Comment: You can find a [possible solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698453/non-modal-questdlg-m-prompt).

Comment: @il_raffa thanks for the link but it is still not what I need. I tested the solution in your link, when the question dialog opens , I can interact with matlab, but still when I click on a link, it will not be opened until I close the question dialog. but thanks anyway